# Composite pattern with custom operations in leaf nodes

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

I'm trying to refactor a tree-like structure using the composite pattern. However, it seems that it doesn't fit exactly into the pattern requirements:

- Different types of leaf nodes are possible: they differ in their attributes and operations (methods)
- Different types of composite objects are possible: they differ in their attributes and operations and have some constraints (in example: a Composite1 object cannot be a Composite2 child; a Composite2 object can be a Composite1 child)

The situation is represented in the next diagram:
[image: Composite with different leaves]

So, I'm wondering which would be the best solution:

1. Since the leaves and composites interfaces are already different
   and node manipulation operations are implemented in the composite
   class, I'm thinking in implementing some operations *isComposite1()*
   and *isComposite2()* and use the schema above.
2. I could also implement node manipulation operations in the abstract class and
   also the ones belonging to the different leaves; then I could
   override them using operations that do nothing if they don't belong
   to that class. This way, the interface would be the same for all the
   classes and I could treat all the nodes the same way...
3. Perhaps Composite is not the pattern to use here? I've read some articles
   suggesting composite + visitor. Could it be useful with this
   structure? Maybe the schema has too many restrictions and
   constraints?

Any guidance or advice is welcome...

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After thinking carefully about @Waog responses, reading more references on the topic and considering again my problem, I think a reasonable solution could look like this :

A Node interface which will be used to compose the structure and specific interfaces for the different types of nodes (be leaf, be composite). Also, default implementation is provided using abstract classes when needed. Below is the diagram with the final situation :

[image: proposed final design diagram]

Thanks a lot to @Waog for your ideas and explanations. I hope I've got the idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: thanks for presenting us a small diagram, instead of 1000 lines of code.

### To your Points

**1.** Since refactoring is about improving the code structure, I would not     recommend this options. Since you build more code upon an imperfect      design, instead of improving it.

**2.** Violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).    I wouldn't recommend you to do so.

**3.1** *Visitor pattern* only makes sense if you want to execute something on all tree elements. Your question so far is only about      modelling a tree structure, so don't use this pattern. It's a       *Behavioral Design Pattern*. You think about an *structural problem* which requires a *structural design pattern* or no pattern at all.      Don't do the *Anti-Pattern* of using too much patterns :)

**3.2** *composite pattern* is ok for your needs, but you need to extend it by a second interface which inherits from the first. The extended pattern would look like this:

[image: extended composite pattern]

**Edit:** after a longer dialog with the OP @predicador37 (see comments), this concrete implementation of the pattern was the result:

[image: concrete implementation of extended composite pattern]

Comment: But, if I use interfaces instead of abstract classes, what about inherited attributes? Should I use two abstract classes inheriting one from the other? And what about the attributes and operations of the Leaf1 class, which are different from the ones of the Leaf2 class?

Comment: @predicador37 to question one: since we're doing design here (which should be independend of the programming language and use general OO paragigms) interfaces may contain properties at this level. If you're language doesn't support attributes in interfaces, then you need a work around. Either you define getters and setters in your interface, or you use an abstract class instead of an interface. I'm not sure about the exact semantic of your attributes, but they look like implementation details to me, which should not be part of an interface.

Comment: @predicador37 to question two and three: the textbook example would be to have a chain of: *interface <- abstractClass1 <- abstractClass2 ... <- finalClass*. And keep all functionality as close as possible to *abstractClass1*, to prevent code duplication. So your common code base is at the level where every child can use it. Unique code is at the level where only one class can use it.

Comment: But in reality this is often regarded as over engineering. Then you could use some less "ideal" structure, to get your stuff working. That's a matter of taste. If you're to inexperienced to decide on that, I'd recommend to first design the textbook example and then cut back some parts of it. You can do some quick UML sketch, instead of implementing it to decide on that.

Comment: I've updated the diagram following your advices... What do you think?

Comment: Hmm... it's a good starting point. One of your requirements was, that not each compositions can be contained in each type of composition. Currently both of your compositions can contain all kinds of nodes. You need to redirect the aggregation edges accordingly. Also the currently unused interfaces (``IDataNode`` and ``ICompositeNode``) may be regarded as over-engineering. If you develop in an agile environment stick to the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) principle instead.

Comment: I see what you say about compositions; I'm giving it another thought. But the interfaces aren't unused, they provide specific methods which are implemented by specific and concrete nodes or abstract classes if behavior is shared... Why do you say they are unused?

Comment: *Deriving from them*, is not the same as *using them* as I mean it. For example no other class than the only child uses ``IDataNode``. At least none is visible in the diagram. So you could define the additional ``operation3()`` directly in the child class ``Leaf1``, instead of introducing an additional interface. This advice is not true anymore, if you have additional children or any kind of dependency (Dependency, Association, Aggregation) on ``IDataNode``.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand... You're helping me so much. I'll give it another try!

Comment: Btw, if your tool allows you to omit derived methods, do so. The Interface ``IDataNode`` would be more readable, if it would only contain ``operation3()`` instead of 5 methods.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; it definitely can, I was including all of them in order to not get lost. I've read your comment late, since I already uploaded the last diagram...

Comment: Great, looks fine to me now! Mind if I copy your solution down into my answer, to decompose question and answer properly and to receive some reputation? :) - If it's ok, I'd apprichiate it, to get the omited-methods-variant from you.

Comment: Sure! You've helped me a lot, I'll think I've improved a lot my understanding of object oriented design. I'll keep on reading GoF Design Patterns and Fowler's books... I've replaced the diagram, I hope this time it's OK. Thanks a lot again, I'll accept your answer with pleasure.

Comment: nice! you could delete your **UPDATE 2** from the question now, to keep the reading flow for future readers. Glad I could help :)